# 360 degrees jquery plugin?

Tags: image-processing

I have found a few plugins that can do this. I.e. Spin a product in 360. My question is more concerned with image handling. Is there an easy way to create these images, so that they can be uploaded in a standard format so you can add them to an online shop generically? Or will I have to take 10 photos for each product, and layer it so it spins?

Answer (score 1):

With AJAX-ZOOM all you need is to point it to a folder with the images. 
Requires php or asp.net

regular example: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/examples/example15.php
online shop: http://www.ajax-zoom.com/demo/magento/index.php/chair.html

Comment: But how much effort is it acquiring the pictures?